# Cosine similarity for sequence of matrices

Tags: python, trigonometry, similarity, word-embedding

I have to calculate cosine similarity between a matrix 'A' and the matrices B1.....Bn. I am currently using 'for loop' to find the cosine similarity matrix between 'A' and 'B1' to 'Bn', as shown in the code snippet. Is there an optimized (time) way to find the cosine similarity between the matrices in a single go (by any transformation or so), instead of looping. I am using 'cosine_similarity' function from 'sklearn.metrics.pairwise'.

```
A = sbert.encode([sentence1, sentence2, sentence3])
B1 = sbert.encode([sentence4, sentence5])
B2 = sbert.encode([sentence6, sentence7, sentence8])
-------------------------------------------------

for i in range(0, n):
    print(cosine_similarity(A, Bi))
```

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs for `A` and `B1, B2,...` so that your loop approach can be compared against any alternatives

Comment: They are sentence embeddings with shape (number of sentences x 384).  So, the number of sentences varies, while embeddings length will be constant.